# Updating knockout observable array fails to update kendo multi select control

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, binding, kendo-ui, multi-select

HTML

```
<select id ="multiSelect" data-bind="options: choices, selectedOptions:   selectedChoice">
</select>
Selected: <strong data-bind="text: selectedChoice"> </strong>
```

Javascript

```
var ViewModel = function() {
   this.choices = ko.observableArray(["apple", "orange", "banana"]);
   this.selectedChoice = ko.observableArray();
};

var vm = new ViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.choices.push("watermelon");
$("#multiSelect").kendoMultiSelect().data("kendoMultiSelect");
vm.choices.push("strawberry");
```

I'm somewhat new to knockout binding. Can anyone explain to me why strawberry does not show up in the multiselect drop down box?

Here's the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/he0xx93s/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo's MultiSelect does not listen for changes made by the knockout observable objects.

What you can use as a work-around is to explicitly update the dataSource of the kendo MultiSelect every time the array changes.

Here is how [to subscribe to a change.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149551/subscribe-to-observable-array-for-new-or-removed-entry-only)

So the main idea should be something like this:

```
vm.choices.subscribe(function(changes) {

    var ms = $("#multiSelect").data("kendoMultiSelect");

    changes.forEach(function(change) {
        if (change.status === 'added') {

            ms.dataSource.push(change.value);
        }
    });

}, null, "arrayChange");
```

In a similar way you can remove/update items with the [remove](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-remove) method of the dataSource.

Or in case of update you can get the specific item (e.g. third item) and use the [set](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/observableobject#methods-set) method of the kendo observable.

```
dataSource.data()[3].set('someProperty', newValue);
```