# Knockout Observable Parent when child is removed

Tags: knockout.js

I have an `observableArray` in my knockout application as shown below:

```
self.Parents = ko.observableArray([
    {
      Father: 'Father-A',
      Mother: 'Mother-A',
      Children: ko.observableArray([
        {Name: 'Child-A1'}, 
        {Name: 'Child-A2'}, 
        {Name: 'Child-A3'}])
    },
    {
      Father: 'Father-B',
      Mother: 'Mother-B',
      Children: ko.observableArray([
        {Name: 'Child-B1'}, 
        {Name: 'Child-B2'}, 
        {Name: 'Child-B3'}])
    }]);
```

And I have `computed observable` on `Parents` variable as shown below:

```
ko.computed(function(){
    alert('Record Updated');
    console.log(self.Parents());
});
```

Now when I add/remove Children to any of the Parent, I believe above computed function should be called as Parent variable is indirectly getting updated when I add/remove child. But it is not working. As a solution of below fiddle, `Record Updated` alert should be displayed.

> [Fiddle - Code Snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/spidercode/afmn2keb/)

So how can I achieve this ?

> **Note:** Here please take a note that this is just a sample I have created. In actual scenario, Parents object is passed to the third party grid library. And if any change occurs in Parent/Child that grid should be updated. That's the reason why I have written `self.Parents()` in `computed function` and not `Children`

Comment: Hi, did you resolve your issue?

Comment: @adiga: Yes. Posted solution as my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the solution my self.

After removing child row, below line of code will notify parents that child data has been changed:

```
self.Parents.valueHasMutated()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ko.toJs`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html) to create a dependency on every observable in an object.

```
ko.computed(function() {
   alert("Children Array changed");
   return ko.toJS(self.Parents());
});
```

You can do your operations inside the `computed` property. But logic inside a `computed` property seems wrong, so you create a subscription to that `computedToJS` property:

```
  self.isDirty = ko.observable(false);

  self.computedToJS = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.toJS(self.Parents());
  });

  self.computedToJS.subscribe(function(value){
    self.isDirty(true);
    // Do all your stuff here.
  });
```

Mind you, this gets triggered for all the `observables`. If you were to change the `Father` property to an `observable` and update the property, then the computed gets triggered again.

[Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adigas/afmn2keb/3/)

You can go through [this blog post](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html) on creating dirty flags in knockout using `ko.toJS`

---

Alternatively, you could create a `ParentViewModel` and add a `subscribe` to the `Children` `observableArray` [which is available from Knockout 3.0+](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/10/08/knockout-3-0-release-candidate-available/#array-change-subscriptions). You can go through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149551/subscribe-to-observable-array-for-new-or-removed-entry-only) for an example.